# PDO::FETCH_OBJECT error

Tags: php, pdo

I have a problem with the `PDO::FETCH_OBJECT` argument. I want to fetch an object and not an array, but when I try this:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=washngo', $config['DB_USERNAME'], $config['DB_PASSWORD']); 
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); //Fetch errors by default ( display any errors during the development process )

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM news');

    $stmt->execute();

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJECT)) { //By default, it fetch an array. The "PDO::FETCH_OBJECT" argument allows us to fetch an object
        print_r($row);
    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I get

> Fatal error: Undefined class constant '`FETCH_OBJECT`' in index.php on line 18.

When I try to let the `fetch()` by default (without `PDO::FETCH_OBJECT()`), it works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Correct is not `PDO::FETCH_OBJECT` but `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`

Comment: Oh my god, what a mistake... Thanks Florent